# Rails: Append number to permalink, if permalink already taken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unique, slug, permalinks, validates-uniqueness-of

I would like to give *John Doe* the permalink ***john-doe-2***, if there already is a ***john-doe-1***.
The number should be the next free one to be appended *("john-doe-**n**")*

Currently my permalinks are generated the usual way:

```
before_validation :generate_slug  
private
def generate_slug   
  self.permalink = self.name.parameterize
end
```

How to implement a **validates_uniqueness_of**-like method, that adds this kind of number to *self.permalink* and then saves the user normally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, ask yourself: Is there a simpler way to do this? I believe there is. If you're already willing to add numbers to your slug, how about always adding a number, like the ID?

```
before_validation :generate_slug

private
def generate_slug
  self.permalink = "#{self.id}-#{self.name.parameterize}"
end
```

This is a very robust way of doing it, and you can even pass the slug directly to the `find` method, which means that you don't really need to save the slug at all.

Otherwise, you can just check if the name + number already exists, and increment n by 1, then recheck, until you find a free number. Please note that this can take a while if there are a lot of records with the same name. This way is also subject to race conditions, if two slugs are being generated at the same time.

Comment: Thanks dvyjones, in this user-centric vanity case it would probably be unfortunate to have a profile permalink associated to its creation date: **user/4208-john-doe** would obviously be newer to the site than **user/1-john-doe**.
So I would opt for your second solution, how would you go about this in the code exactly?

Comment: Well, john-doe-1 would also be newer than john-doe-2. But to answer your question, I believe this will work: https://gist.github.com/456d87a12bdd6aa30779. I haven't tested it though.

Comment: Your gist is working, just prepended the model name ("User") to your _where_ queries and added **if self.name_changed?** to the method. To prevent new numbers from being added to the same user when saving.

Comment: Just a fair warning though: This will get slower as more users with the same name registers.